# SSRS 2016 ReportServer DBs in Basic AG

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, ssrs-2016

I have a 2 node cluster on which I need to setup AlwaysOn since it is a standard edition we would be going with Basic AGs. I can easily get the user databases added into the AGs but I am not sure about how it would be if we add the ReportingServer databases into the Basic AG. Is there a documentation that suggests how it needs to be added in a Basic AG. Also, what are the precautionary measures once should take in order to make sure that in the event of a failover it works correctly. I am also a little unsure how it would be since both the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB would be in 2 separate AGs...will this cause problems etc.

Appreciate the guidance on this.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to put the report server and the report server tempdb in seperate AGs?

Comment: @MAO - Basic AG. You can have only one DB per AG...right?